# Insert attachment from URL with query string WP

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to insert an image from a URL that has a query string, e.g.,

```
https://example.com/screenshot-1.png?rev=2780533
```

However, it's not working.

If there is not a query string, the insert does work, e.g.,

```
$image_url = https://ps.w.org/custom-upload-folder/assets/screenshot-1.png
```

CODE EX:

```
$image_url = https://ps.w.org/custom-upload-folder/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=2780533

if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Http' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-http.php';
}
                   
$http     = new \WP_Http();
$response = $http->request( $image_url );

if( is_wp_error( $response ) || $response['response']['code'] != 200 ) { return false; }
                  
$mirror = wp_upload_bits( basename( $image_url ), null, $response['body'] );

if ( ! empty( $mirror['error'] ) ) { return false; }
```

POST: https://gist.github.com/m1r0/f22d5237ee93bcccb0d9

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-http.php

Comment: Query string not added here `'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . $file_name,`

Comment: It worked with url with format: name.jpg, name.png ...
Not worked with url format look like:
https://example.com/screenshot-1.png?rev=2780533

Also It's only add to media library, not attach to the post